# Bifurcate iTunes playlist from folders

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, mpmediaquery

I want to show all folders and playlists in my app just like iTunes does. I do get playlists from `MPMediaQuery`, but I cannot bifurcate if its playlist or a folder.

Below is my code:

```
let playlistQuery = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()
if let arrPlaylists = playlistQuery.collections{
    for playlist in arrPlaylists {
        if let mediaPlaylist = playlist as? MPMediaPlaylist{
            //got the playlist and all folders as playlists
        }
    }
}
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568603/show-playlist-folder-in-ios-app) about some private api to bifurcate, but as of iOS 9.3, those properties are not available either.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MPConcreteMediaPlaylist 0x15594c40> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key isFolder.'
```

I do get folders information as if they are playlist, all hierarchical folders are displayed in root. Like I have directory structure like:

```
D1
--D11
----D111
------SomePlaylist
```

Then it shows like I have `playlists` like below:

```
D1 (Containing items in SomePlaylist)
D11 (Containing items in SomePlaylist)
D111 (Containing items in SomePlaylist)
```

Is there any way I can bifurcate folders from playlist and show them in its original hierarchy?

Note: iTunes app shows this very well as it should.